# which library should i use to import the package 'javax.obex.ClientSession' in javase?

Tags: java, bluetooth, obex

i got a program that send file to mobile device. After opening it in the NetBeans IDE it shows error in the lines shown below

```
import javax.obex.ClientSession;
import javax.obex.HeaderSet;
import javax.obex.Operation;
```

it shows error as package does not exist. what should i do to correct this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bluecove.org/

Here's the download page: http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/downloads/list

Answer (score 3):

[findJAR](http://www.findjar.com) is a useful JAR search engine that will help you find jars containing a specified class.

Just search for `javax.obex.ClientSession` and it will tell you that it is present in [bluecove-2.1.0.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/net/sf/bluecove/bluecove/2.1.0/bluecove-2.1.0.jar) and also where you can download the jar from.